# Peculiar properties of metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

V. Bogachev in his "[Real and Functional Analysis](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-38219-3)" (page 6) makes the following remark:

"Although all the definitions given above coincide with those introduced in elementary calculus for sets on the real line, general metric spaces can substantially diffeer by their properties from the real line and $\mathbb{R}^n$ and their subsets. We shall have many occasions to see this below, but now we only observe that even subsets of the plane with the usual Euclidean metric can have rather peculiar properties. For example, if we take three points $a, b$ and $c$ on the plane such that $|a-b| = 1, |b-c|=2$ and $|a-c| = 5/2$, then in the obtained metric space the ball of radius $2$ centered at $b$ strictly contains the ball of the larger radius $9/4$ centered at $a$."

First question: is he using the standard euclidean metric here? If so, then how do we know that there exist three such points with the given properties?

Second question: Let $B(b, 2)$ and $B(a, 9/4)$ be the balls of radius $2$ and $9/4$ centered at $a$ and $b$ respectively. We want to show that $$B(a, 9/4) \subset B(b, 2).$$ Let $x \in B(a, 9/4)$. We want to show that $x \in B(b, 2)$ or $|x-b|<2$. However, $$|x-b| \leq |x-a|+|a-b| < 9/4 + 1 = 13/4 >2.$$ Clearly, this triangle inequality method fails. Do you guys know any way to show this claim?

I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, the Euclidean metric. The points exist because the distances between them satisfy the triangle inequalities. Alternatively, you can give a concrete example putting $a$ at the origin, $b=(1,0)$ and $c$ determined by the intersection of the appropriate (ordinary) circles. $B(b,2)=\{b,a,c\}$ (since they said strictly contains, I assume they mean the closed ball) while $B(a,9/4)=\{a,b\}$. Remember, the space is the set $\{a,b,c\}$. Membership to a ball can just be checked one point at a time.

Comment: What the author is considering seems to be the metric space consisting of *only* the points $a,b,c$. Which surely exist as you can find a triangle with sides $1,2,2.5$.